# matching parentheses using a file

Tags: python

I am trying to match parentheses from a line in a file but when I use the code below without getting data from a file and entering it instead it works and matched the parentheses. I don't know how to allow it to work with numbers and letters in between too.

i have tried many different ways but this has worked the best so far. I think there is firstly something wrong with what i am printing but i have tried everything that i know to fix that. i am also new to python so it might not be the best code.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self._items == []

    def push(self,item):
        self._items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self._items.pop()

stack = Stack()

open_list = ["[","{","("] 
close_list = ["]","}",")"] 

def open_file():
    file = open("testing.txt","r")
    testline = file.readline()
    count = 1
    while testline != "":
        testline = testline[:-1]
        check(testline,count)
        testline = file.readline()
        count = count + 1


def check(testline,count): 
    stack = [] 
    for i in testline:
        if i in open_list: 
            stack.append(i) 
        elif i in close_list: 
            pos = close_list.index(i) 
            if ((len(stack) > 0) and
                (open_list[pos] == stack[len(stack)-1])): 
                stack.pop() 
            else: 
                print ("Unbalanced")
                print (count)
    if len(stack) == 0: 
        print ("Balanced")
        print (count)


def main():
    open_file()

if __name__=="__main__": 
    main()
```

output:

if the file contains

dsf(hkhk[khh])

ea{jhkjh[}}

hksh[{(]

sd{hkh{hkhk[hkh]}}]

the output is

```
Balanced
1
Unbalanced
2
Unbalanced
2
Unbalanced
3
Unbalanced
4
Balanced
4
```

The first four are correct but it adds 2 and i have no idea where it is coming from. I need the count for later purposes when i am printing (ie line 1 is balanced)

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your `open_file()` function.

1. The while-loop finishes only when `testline == ""` returns `true`. So when later you do `check(testline)`, you actually give the function an empty string, so it can't really do it's job.
2. I assume the purpose of the while loop is to remove the newline character `\n` for each line in the file? The problem is you're not saving the intermediate lines anywhere.  Then when `file.readline()` returns a `""` because the file doesn't have any more lines, you give that empty string to the function.

#### Some suggestions

```py
# A way to remove newlines
testline = testline.replace("\n", "")

# Check all the lines
lines = file.readlines()
count = len(lines)

for testline in lines:
    testline = testline.replace("\n", "")
    check(testline)

# And if you're sure that the file will have only one line
testline = file.readline()[:1] # read line and remove '\n'
check(testline)
```

Remember, a string is just a list full of characters. So you can do `len(string)` to see the length. Or you can do `len(file.readlines())` to see how many lines a file has. Either way, you can get rid of the `count` variable.

#### Printing

When you call `print(check())` it first calls the `check()` function with no parameters, so it can't actually check anything. That's why you can't see the right print statement. 
A suggested edit would be to move the print statement at the end of your `open_file()` function, so that you have `print(check(testline))`

Another possible solution would be to put a return statement in your `open_file()` function.

```py
def open_file():
    # Some code...
    return check(testline)

def check():
    # Some code...

print(open_file())
```

The easiest will probably be to replace the `return` statements in `check()` with `print` statements though.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed those but I think I am printing something wrong at the end and nothing is printing at all. I have tried using all the variables i could think of but it's still not working

Comment: The reply got longer than I expected, so I edited my original post. Take a look, this should solve your problems.

Comment: yes that worked! i don't want to be annoying but i encountered another problem and i was wondering if you could look at it. I can just ask another question if its a problem

Comment: Now that you removed the `return` statments from the `check()` function, if the code encounters that the expression is unbalanced it will still keep iterating, or will print "Balanced" once the stack is empty. Just add an empty `return` statement after the prints in `check()`.

Answer (score 0):

Time to learn the basis of debugging...

@emilanov has given hints for the `open_file` function, so I will focus on the `check` function.

```
for i in range (0,len(testline),1):
```

Is probably not what you want: `i` will take integer values from `0` to `len(testline) -1`. The rule is: *when things go wrong, use a debugger or add trace prints*. Here

```
for i in range (0,len(testline),1): 
    print(i)        # trace - comment out for production code
```

would have made the problem evident.

What you want is probably:

```
for i in testline:
```

Comment: yes, thank you, I see what you mean but I still think that my printing line at the very end is a problem 'print(check())' but I don't know what variable to print since I changed it to receive data from a file as opposed to entering it.